# Cannot resolve symbol 'Auth' for google integration in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-signin

i am new in androidstudio. i have done integration of google in eclipse but am having issues in studio.
i am following step by step from this site : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in?configured=true

but i am having an issue. i am getting an error that Cannot resolve symbol 'Auth' which i need for API and also cannot resolve 'SignInButton', see the code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
       mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
    .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

this is my project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is my app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.creaa.admin.googlesignin"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

- Put `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` beneath `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`.
- Add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'` inside `dependencies` block. This will add related dependencies to your project.

Comment: getting this error: Error:(20, 25) error: cannot find symbol variable Auth
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: thank you. it worked now, had to restart studio but it worked after adding your lines.

Comment: but y dont they provide this on the google website>? beginners like me face problems like this

Comment: @ParthAnjaria It's `gms`. The configuration doc is here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Comment: If someone from Google read this: Please update your examples. This is the second time an example doesn't work.

Comment: Latest version/infos https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

Comment: I had to put "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" all the way at the bottom of the file

Comment: @Tyler - yes, I did too.  If you put the "apply pluging: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" at the top directly under the one for application, then some people get a version conflict error that suggests downgrading the google-services items to 9.0.0 which isn't what you want to do.

Answer (score 6):

With the latest version (2.2.2) what I had to do in order to fix this issue was to add the line below as a dependency into my `app/build.gradle` file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add the dependencies for **Firebase** Authentication and Google Sign-In to your app-level **build.gradle** file:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, add **compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1** *(your project's latest version)* in your app level gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' from dependencies to top of your gradle file, just under apply plugin: 'com.android.application'.

EDIT:

Make sure that you have installed the Extras/Google Repository from the SDK Manager and added the compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0' into your dependency scope.

Comment: still getting this error after build :Error:(20, 25) error: cannot find symbol variable Auth

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue. I solved it by adding this line in app level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**(at the bottom of the file (important))**

and this line in app level dependencies section,

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
```

(latest version, at the time when I am writing this answer)

Here's the [link to the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk).

Answer (score 0):

Add this in dependency block in your app gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. open your ANDROID STUDIO
2. open TOOLS
3. select FIREBASE
4. select the authentication
5. and click on the "Add firebase authentication to your app" button.

done!

(note: make sure you are connected to the internet.)