# Authentication with email and password Issue on Android Studio

Tags: java, android

How I can enable authentication with email and password?? When i enable gradle didn't complete successfully.
When i click on Authentication with email and password button. Following(link of image) changes are need to enable it. But when I accept it then Gradle didn't Finish successfully.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwdTR.jpg)

Here is the link of an image that show error after accept the changes. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFRKj.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve symbol 'Auth' for google integration in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773166/cannot-resolve-symbol-auth-for-google-integration-in-android-studio)

Comment: Please put all relevant information into the question itself, don't rely on external links. They tend to disappear which makes the question useless for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

delete

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

add only:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
```

In order to enable auth with email and password, you should go to console and change setting.
[image]

Comment: then authentication with email and password is disable.